# Apply border to div with rounde corners?

Tags: html, css

How do I add a border to a div with round corners?
When I try, the corners look weird - the border wont wrap all the way round.

Comment: Increase the width a little. Try adding a slight box-shadow as well.

Comment: Look at this site http://border-radius.com/, apply a radius and you will see the border corner css in the centre. You will also be able to see the full css for the div through your developer toolbar (F12) - this might help. Post your code for more help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compatibility for older versions of IE may be an issue, but the example below should work on modern browsers:

**CSS**

```
div{
    width: 50px;
    height: 20px;
    padding 5px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px; /* future proofing */
    -khtml-border-radius: 10px; /* for old Konqueror browsers */
    background-color: green;
}
```

Here's an **[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gKz8N/1/)**

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/rounded-corners/